# UVs on Blender and Substance Painter are different

Tags: texturing, uv

I have this problem with UVs,

In blender my UVs look like this:
[image]

For example Substance Painter UV looks like this:

[image]

There are weird spiky bits in the bottom right where as in Blender's UVs there aren't.

What is the problem? Can someone explain?

Comment: This is.. extremely odd. Perhaps provide your .BLEND file using [this website](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) so that I can try baking as well, and see if the problem occurs.

Comment: Those in the second image aren't necessarily UVs, rather than baked image using that unwrap. Usually that happens if you change something within mesh and don't update UV map.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3189" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3189/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to export your model to other softwares (like substance painter), you have to apply your modifier first.

When applied, you can see that your UV are broken, you have to re-unwrap.

---

*Little tips after seeing your .blend : when you used mirror modifier, be sure to have all your half-mesh on the same side. This will prevent arrival of weird artefacts or bugs.*

Comment: I see that spiky things now in blender